# I need new eyes on this jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just practicing some basic jquery.  I am making a test feature slider that has two nav buttons to tell it to go left and right.  The jquery I wrote for the right button works perfectly and I used the same framework for the left nav button yet it doesn't work at all.  I have no idea why.  I've tried moving the position of the code for the left nav button and a couple other things that aren't working at all.  Have a look if you wish and feel free to share you jquery wisdom with me.
Thanks in advance!

```
var main = function() {

        $('.slideLeft').click(function () {

        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();  

        if (prevSlide.length === 0) {
            prevSlide = $('.slide3');
        }     

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');


    });


    $('.slideRight').click(function () {

        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide1');
        }     

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');


    });


};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Can  you post the relevant markup? Also, what do the `.next()` & `.prev()` functions look like?

Comment: prev() and next() are jquery functions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9sw1mtrt/1/ - looks fine - can you update your markup in the fiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: Okay, I updated the markup in the fiddle.  What you had before worked using my jquery, so is the problem not in the jquery?  I'm new so don't hold back any harsh criticisms.  Like I said, this is just me playing around.

Comment: which fiddle? @JasonCarrick. Link?

Comment: ok final answer @JasonCarrick

Comment: can you mark my answer as correct please )) @JasonCarrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9sw1mtrt/6/

Change you class in html:

```
slideleft
```

instead of

```
slideLeft
```

Comment: @SaidKholov Hey, thanks for your help.  Looking at your fiddle made me realize that the 'L' in .slideLeft was capitalized in JS and not in the html.  I fixed that and my original code worked.  So frustrating!  Thanks again!